# потоки в dll delphi

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, dll

Есть DLL, в ней создаю поток, который выполняет основные действия. Понадобилось параллельно выполнять еще действия, создал второй поток, но при запуске двух потоков одновременно, то и 1 перестает работать. Если не запускать второй поток, то первый выполняется хорошо. Для примера создал второй поток, который ничего не делает, но все равно не работает.

```
TMyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

TMyThread2 = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  MyThread: TMyThread;
  MyThread2: TMyThread2;

...

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  msg: TMSG;
  FComponentUSB: TComponentUSB;
begin
  FComponentUSB := TComponentUSB.CreatE(nil);
  try
    PeekMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);
    while not Terminated and GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0) do
    begin
      TranslateMessage(msg);
      DispatchMessage(msg);
    end;
  finally
    FComponentUSB.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyThread2.Execute;
begin
  while true do
  begin
    sleep(1000);
  end;
end;

begin
  MyThread := TMyThread.Create(False);
  MyThread2 := TMyThread2.Create(False);

end.
```

Может я чего-то не понимаю, но по идее, потоки не должны блочить друг друга или основной поток. Можете помочь разобраться ?

Comment: Что-то Вы не договариваете. Как Вы узнаете, что первый поток перестал работать? Если он перестал, значит в него не приходят сообщения. Мог быть еще вариант, что завис обработчик сообщения, но у Вас нет обработчиков

Comment: @AntonShchyrov первый поток у меня следит за подключением усб [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709936/delphi-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-usb), когда запускаю оба потока, то первый поток не срабатывает при подключении флэхи, а когда запускаю только первый поток, то все норм

Comment: @AntonShchyrov вот щас заметил, что код работает через раз, именно поток 1, который следит за усб, то он видит усб (я для теста вывожу сообщение, что подкл усб), то не видит. Код не менял, просто пару раз поставлял флэху. Если поток 2 не запускать, то всегда видит подключение усб

Comment: еще немного понаблюдав понял, что именно первый раз, когда только заинжектил длл и вставил флэшку, то не всегда видит, что подключена, последующие разы вродь видит

Comment: чет я ничего не пойму, убрал запуск потока 2 и все норм, сразу видит, что вставил флэху, а если запускать оба потока, то первый раз почти никогда не видит, а при последующих все норм

Comment: Ну, я в предыдущей теме предупреждал, что в dllMain лучше ничего не делать :) Хотя поведение странное. А зачем 2 потока? И второй вопрос - а что если после создания потоков попробовать раз 10 вызвать `PostThreadMessage(myThread.ThreadID, WM_USER, 0, 0)` ? Ну и последнее - не выводите из dll, тем более - из вторичных потоков сообщения. Пишите в лог.

Comment: @kami дык яж в dllMain ничего не делаю, кроме создания потока, вы сами в прошлый раз сказали. Второй поток мониторит подключение nas, я писал вам в чате. Попробую. Я чисто для теста, потом убрал вывод сообщений, но результат не изменился.

Comment: Да, я это говорил. И когда писал ответ - уточнил, что и это не очень хорошо (со ссылкой). И даже дал рекомендацию - если есть возможность после инжекта dll вызвать функцию из нее, то лучше это сделать и убрать код из dllMain.
Что мешает мониторить оба вида событий внутри одной оконной процедуры? Всего-то два if или 1 case.

Comment: @kami дык да, я бы мониторил, но ведь я nas проверяю через cmd, и проверка может занимать несколько десятков секунд, что плохо скажется на проверке усб. Яб проверял тем же способом, что и усб, если бы знал какой тип нужно проверять

Comment: @kami не помог вызов `PostThreadMessage(myThread.ThreadID, WM_USER, 0, 0)` , переписал код, как вы написали в ответе прошлой темы, в результате получилось так  [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/czPHG3eA), но опять первый коннект флэшки не видит, а вот последующие нормально

Comment: @kami на соседнем борде http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=411244&st=0&#entry3738171 подсказали в чем может быть дело, и первым пунктом был а проверка результата USBRegister. Как оказалось, при запуске 2 потоков USBRegister занимает 5-6 сек, а я вставлял флэшку сразу после инжекта, мне не особо понятно почему заняло больше времени, но вродь причину нашли, спасибо

Comment: @kami а почему я не могу заинжектить длл в тот же notepad.exe ? с чем это связано ?

Comment: 32битные dll могут работать только с 32битными процессами. 64 - с 64битными. Посему если нужно и там и там - нужно 2 dll, скомпилированные под них. Благо, в Delphi при нормальном написании кода это 2 раза мышкой щелкнуть.

Comment: @kami у меня инжектит только в мои процессы, напротив процесса пишет 32 бита, значит работает 32 битными процессами, но никак не получается заинжектить в чужой процесс, в диспетчере показывает, что процесс 32 бит, но почему-то эффекта 0. Создам наверн тему и покажу, как инжечу, мб я чтот не так делаю

Answer (score 1):

Судя по вашим комментариям к вопросу, вы создаете потоки в `DllMain`. Там этого делать категорически нельзя!

**Существуют ограничения** на действия, которые можно делать в `DllMain`.

[На картинке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) видно, что происходит перед выполнением `DllMain` и после.

[Чуть ниже картинки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#general_best_practices) написано, что **нельзя** делать в `DllMain`: **создавать процессы**, **потоки**, загружать библиотеки, выходить из потока и т.д. Там большой список.

Дополнительная информация по `DllMain` есть [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) в разделе Remarks.

Чтобы обойти эти ограничения, вам нужно создание потоков вынести из `DllMain` в экспортируемую функцию.

Comment: Категорически - это лишнее. Потоки в DllMain создавать можно. Перечитайте этот пункт еще раз: "Call CreateThread. Creating a thread can work if you do not synchronize with other threads, but it is risky". В данном случае много вопросов возникает не на создание потока, а на то, что он делает. Вот тут синхронизация с основным потоком, который делает в это время инжект - сделает дедлок, но у ТС другая проблема, судя по комментариям.