# DLL Injection delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, code-injection

Пытаюсь заинжектить длл в чужой процесс

```
function GetPID(ExeFileName: string): dword;
var
ContinueLoop: boolean;
FSnapshotHandle: THandle;
FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
UpEFN: string;
begin
result:= 0;
UpEFN:= UpperCase(ExeFileName);
FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
FProcessEntry32.dwSize := Sizeof(FProcessEntry32);
ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);

while integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
begin
if ((UpperCase(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile)) = UpEFN)
or (UpperCase(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile) = UpEFN)) then
begin
result := FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID;
break;
end;
ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
end;
CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;

function SetSeDebugPrivilege:boolean;
var
ht:THandle;
luid:TLargeInteger;
tkp:TTokenPrivileges;
rl:Cardinal;
begin
if OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, ht)
then begin
LookupPrivilegeValue(nil, 'SeDebugPrivilege', luid);
tkp.Privileges[0].Luid:=luid;
tkp.PrivilegeCount:=1;
tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes:=SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
if AdjustTokenPrivileges(ht, false, tkp, 0, nil, rl)
then result:=true
else result:=false;
end else result:=false;
end;

function Load_DLL(DllName: PChar; PID: dword): boolean;
var hProc: dword;
lpStartAddress, pmem: pointer;
wrb, lpThId: dword;
begin
hProc:= OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS or PROCESS_VM_WRITE, true, PID);
if (hProc<>0) then
begin
lpStartAddress:= GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('kernel32.dll'), 'LoadLibraryA');
pmem:= VirtualAllocEx(hProc, nil, 255, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
if (pmem=nil) then result:=false else
begin
if not WriteProcessMemory(hProc, pmem, DllName, Length(DllName), wrb)
then result:=false else
if (dword(Length(DllName)) = wrb) then
begin
result:=CreateRemoteThread(hProc, nil, 0, lpStartAddress, pmem, 0, lpThId)<>0;
end else result:=false;
end;
end else result:=false;
end;

procedure LoadInAllActiveProcesses(DllName: PChar);
var
ContinueLoop: BOOL;
FSnapshotHandle: THandle;
FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
begin
FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
FProcessEntry32.dwSize := Sizeof(FProcessEntry32);
ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
while integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
begin
Load_DLL(DllName, FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID);
ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
end;
CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;

......

const DllName = 'dll.dll';
var PID: dword;
begin
SetSeDebugPrivilege;
PID:=GetPID('notepad++.exe'); // показывает в дз, что процесс 32 бит
if (PID>0)
then Load_DLL(DllName, PID);
end.
```

Но не инжектит, если указать ехе, который я так же создал в delphi 7, то инжектит нормально (в дз так же показывает, что процесс 32 битный).

система у меня вин10 64бит, пишу на делфи 7

Можете подсказать, в чем дело ?

Comment: Какая API-функция и с какой ошибкой отказывается работать?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ошибки нет. Моя история берет начала с создания длл для мониторинга подключения усб [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709936/delphi-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-usb?noredirect=1&lq=1). Когда я инжектю в свои процессы, то все норм, а когда в чужие, то нет. Сделал вывод результата `USBRegister`, в своих процессах выводит `true`, но в чужих ничего не выводит, видимо, что не доходит до этого

Comment: 1. Для LoadLibrary нужно обязательно использовать полный путь к dll 2. Нужно взять ProcessExplorer и посмотреть, есть ли в списке целевого процесса нужная dll 3. Подавляющее большинство исполняемых файлов - unicode. Могут возникнуть проблемы при использовании Ansi-функций, но это зависит от многих факторов. Я сталкивался с проблемой русских символов в путях к файлам.

Comment: @Lolidze в вашем коде отсутствуют проверки кодов возврата из API и поэтому я не понимаю на основании чего вы делаете вывод что "ошибки нет". Читайте документацию на все API, проверйете что они возвращают, смотрите где ошибка.

Comment: В WriteProcessMemory вы ошиблись, там надо `WriteProcessMemory(hProc, pmem, DllName, Length(DllName)+1, wrb)` asciiz стандарт предполагает ещё один символ.

Comment: @kami вы, как всегда, правы. Использовал полный путь и длл загрузилась нормально в процесс notepad++.exe (смотрел по ProcessExplorer ) , хотя длл лежало рядом, ток странно, что все пахало на "своих" процессах без полного пути. Думаю, можете оформлять ответ, спасибо большое

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а можете кинуть литру, чтоб я почитал и понял, как все это организовать ? спасибо

Comment: @nick_n_a неа, так наоборот не пашет

Comment: @Lolidze MSDN читайте

Comment: Думаю, вам надо объединить код, получившийся после моих рекомендаций с тем, что посоветовал вам Владимир. И самому оформить как ответ, это будет значительно полезнее сообществу, чем мое "Для LoadLibrary всегда следует использовать полный путь, кому надо подробнее - вот ссылка https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx раздел Remarks  "