# Сокеты: не выполняется событие

Tags: delphi, сокет

Доброй ночи!
Имеется:

- клиентская часть (служба)
- в ней поток (создается динамически).
- в потоке динамически создается сокет который подключается к серверу, а также работает цикл while общаясь с сервером. (Компонент ClientSocket).

От клиента сообщения передаются серверу нормально, но не принимаются ответные сообщения (не срабатывает событие OnRead).
Почитав по этому поводу понял, что в отдельном потоке все сообщения необходимо обрабатывать самостоятельно и нашел код, но данный код не помог (должен быть внутри цикла while):

```
if PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) then
begin
    TranslateMessage(Msg); //не обязательно т.к. нажатия клавиш передавать не будем
    DispatchMessage(Msg);
end;
```

CommView сообщения от сервера клиенту видит. Другие события (OnConnect, OnError, OnDisconnect) работают нормально, всё прекрасно работает кроме события OnRead. Внутри цикла, при общении с сервером данный код успешно выполняется, т.е. сообщения успешно доходят, но что-то идет не так:

```
if(ClientSocket1.Socket.ReceiveLength>0) then //если имеется какие либо принятые данные
  Log('ok'); //моя ф-ция для записи логов
```

И мой код:

Первый кусок

```
TMyThread = class(TThread)
  // соеденение
  procedure ClientSocketConnect(Sender: TObject;  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  // данные из сокета
  procedure OnRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  // отключение
  procedure ClientSocketDisconnect(Sender: TObject;  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  // ошибка
  procedure ClientSocketErr(Sender: TObject;
```

Второй кусок

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  FreeOnTerminate := true;
  try
    //подключение к серверу
    ClientSocket1:=TClientSocket.Create(nil);
    ClientSocket1.OnConnect:=ClientSocketConnect;
    ClientSocket1.OnDisconnect:=ClientSocketDisconnect;
    ClientSocket1.OnError:=ClientSocketErr;
    ClientSocket1.OnRead:=OnRead;
    ClientSocket1.Name:='Srv';
    ClientSocket1.Host:='127.0.0.1';
    ClientSocket1.Port:=1234;
    ClientSocket1.ClientType:=ctBlocking;
    ClientSocket1.Open;
```

Третий кусок

```
procedure TMyThread.OnRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  Log('ClientSocketRead выполнен'); //моя функция для записи логов
end;
```

Событие ClientSocketConnect создано полностью аналогично, все тоже самое, но тем не менее оно выполняется, а OnRead не хочет, прошу подсказать, в чем проблема? Спасибо!

Comment: Второй кусок (`procedure TMyThread.Execute;`) вы привели не польностью, этот метод должен содержать цикл, т.е. пока работает этот метод потока - поток существует, как только метод завершился, поток прекращает работу, и при `FreeOnTerminate := true;` уничтожается

Comment: Про это я знаю, я лишь показал как создается сокет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710240/192901
см. код в Execute

Comment: а, стоп. Вы же работаете в блокирующем режиме сокета. Тогда цикл выборки сообщений вам вообще не нужен, ведь соединение работает в отдельном своем потоке

Comment: Частичный выход из ситуации есть, не сильно хороший это в цикле в потоке принимать сообщения так: ClientSocket.Socket.ReceiveText; предварительно проверив длину сообщений

Comment: Согласно [документации](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TClientSocket.OnRead) при использовании клиента сокета в блокирующем режиме, необходимо использовать объект `TWinSocketStream` для чтения данных из соединения и в теле потока нужно вызвать его метод `WaitForRead()` чтобы поставить на ожидание получения данных. Ну и получается все равно нужно цикл в потоке запускать, если не надо убивать поток после однократного получения сообщения. Также еще одна [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969186) по теме